# how to add Zero to Format Time using String Format class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to format date and time with given number like

```kotlin
val time = 4
val hour = 5
```

how to write it like that 4:05

```kotlin
String.format("%d:%d", time.hours, time.minutes)
```

Comment: You need to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format for display time is required way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this format:

```
  String.format("%02d:%02d",time.hours ,time.minutes)
```

use `%02d` instead of `%d`

Comment: i think its %02d  also i have to add 0

Comment: @CrystalApps, yes use %02d